# (Linux) How to get back java apps(waiting input), if ssh close?

Tags: java, linux, service

When running a java apps, or something else 
lets say in ssh:

```
**please type y/n :**
```

the apps keep waiting and keep running.
the question is how do i get back to this situation to let me type y or n if ssh close?

or a running java service can be interrupt and accept new command while running (after the ssh close)?

The ANSWER is **"GNU SCREEN"**

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use screen?

Comment: Where does ssh come into it? What's the question?

Comment: Hi SBI, i using centos 6.3 without GUI.

Comment: Hi EJP, Adam Bliss has describe my question quite well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're saying you ssh'd to another machine and ran this program, then the SSH connection closed while it was waiting for the prompt.

As SBI pointed out, you could try running the "screen" program, then running your java command inside "screen" This creates a fake TTY for your program; you can then close SSH, and come back to where you were with "screen -x".

If you didn't start your process inside "screen", I don't know any way to "get back" to the TTY it's waiting on for input. However, if you wanted a way to communicate with a running service without using the TTY, you could consider using "kill" to send the process a particular signal. The java code could then trap the signal and act accordingly.

Comment: hmm, seem like your answer is correct! let me do test first! will be back after i tested.

Comment: Thanks! GNU Screen is so powerful!